# Como alterar o width e height de um RelativeLayout pelo código Java

Tags: java, android-layout

Eu quero saber como eu ajusto os valores de width e height de cada relative layout, independentemente, do meu XML através da classe Java respectiva. Eu já sei como ajustar o width, height e outros parâmetros dos botões presentes no meu layout da forma desejada, mas os botões estão dentro de relatives layouts e esses relative layouts precisam ser ajustados tbm e não sei como fazer isso.
Segue o código XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="227dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSAE"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_barcode2"
        android:textColorLink="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="244dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBuscarNome"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_busca" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="244dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSocorro"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_socorro" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="383dp"
    android:layout_height="113dp"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAtualizar"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnSobre"
        android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnFecharApp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnFecharApp"
        android:background="@drawable/reload" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnConfig"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="19dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnSobre"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnSobre"
        android:background="@drawable/config" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFecharApp"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="67dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="67dp"
        android:background="@drawable/fechar"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnAtualizar"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnAtualizar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSobre"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"

        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnConfig"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnAtualizar"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnAtualizar"
        android:background="@drawable/sobre" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

No código Java uso o seguinte para configurar os parâmetros dos botões:

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1= (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) btnSAE.getLayoutParams();

    //alguns comandos para cálculos envolvendo as métrica do display (DisplayMetrics)
    //após os cálculos tenho as variáveis indicando os pixels necessários
    //para ajustar meu layout ao celular do usuário

    layoutParams1.setMargins(l,t,r,b);
    layoutParams1.setMarginEnd(e);
    layoutParams1.setMarginStart(s);
    btnSAE.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);
    btnSAE.setHeight(h);
    btnSAE.setWidth(w);
```

Mas isso só ajusta o botão e não o Relative Layout em que está incluso (o width e height). Como faço?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalmente não é necessário/aconselhável atribuir valores absolutos a `android:layout_width` e `android:layout_height` dos layouts.

O normal é atribuir `match_parent` ou `wrap-content`.

No entanto pode alterar, via código java, esses valores da mesma forma que altera em qualquer outra view. Apenas necessita de lhe atribuir um `@id` para o poder referenciar e obtê-lo com `findViewById()`.